# Having trouble deploying my app to Heroku blank page and console errors when the build succeeds?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I am attempting to deploy my dev portfolio using React + Node.js and Express on Heroku and the build has succeeded and says it’s deployed, but I keep getting a blank screen or a dark screen. I am very confused and I was wondering if it is the structure of the syntax in my server.js file causing the problem, or anything in the package.json or even my index.html. I am currently getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). I suspect it could be that I am pointing to it incorrectly in my server.js file.

If anybody could give suggestions on how to resolve this that would be amazing. I’m so close to deploying it. It has been frustrating and I have tried a lot of different suggestions on stack overflow.

Here is my index.html file:

```html
<html lang="en"></html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
    <link rel="icon" type='image/x-icon' href="favicon.ico">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" >
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app">

      <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" href="text/css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" >
    <script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


    <link href="public/css/layout.css">
    <link href="public/css/media-queries.css">
    <link href="public/css/magnific-popup.css">

    <title>Kevin Gillooly Dev Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

Here is my server.js file:

```html
require ('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const buildPath = ('build/index.html');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const sendGrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.use(cors());

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});

server.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('API Status: Running')
});

server.use(express.static(__dirname));

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

const REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY =`${process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY}`
server.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
  sendGrid.setApiKey(REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  console.log(req.body);
  const msg = {
      to: 'kevgill95@gmail.com',
      from: req.body.email,
      subject: req.body.subject,
      text: req.body.message
  }

  sendGrid.send(msg)
      .then(result => {
          res.status(200).json({
            success: true
          });

      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log('error: ', err);
          res.status(401).json({
            success: false
          })
      })
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Here is my package.json file:

```html
{
  "name": "dev-personal-portfolio",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://kev-personal-portfolio.herokuapp.com/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "secure":false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@lawcket/websocket": "^0.1.5",
    "@material/textfield": "^6.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.4",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "material-components-web": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.10",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-mdl": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "3": "^2.1.0",
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0"
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**(EDIT)**
Here are the screenshots of how my directory is laid out

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnY9X.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0DQz.png)

**(More EDIT)**
Here is the screenshot of my folder structure now.
[image]

** EDIT AGAIN **
Here is my folder structure

[image: updated folders]

Comment: Can you share an image of your directory

Comment: Also, could you clear a few things up. It looks like you want to deploy a monolith i.e. client and server within the same repository. However, the package you linked to is your client package. I would expect you to have your server package at the root level.

Comment: @Hyetigran I just posted the screenshots under the edit. That should clear up that my server is in the root of the project. I am also not using the client folder.

Comment: Thanks. See my answer below. Let me know if any of the steps are unclear, I can add more detail.

Comment: @Hyetigran
I moved my src, public, and my node modules into the client folder, it says over 5k changes but that should be alright right? I was going to commit those and then run a build again and git push heroku master. I already have my env's set on heroku too so that should be alright. I was going to call it for now and continue tomorrow. Thanks again

Comment: those 5k changes are due to node_modules and/or package-lock.json which is best not to commit to a repository. Make sure to add it to your .gitignore file in the client folder

Comment: @Hyetigran Okay I was just making sure. I moved the necessary files into the client folder and it's alright if the path is still the same in the gitignore for /node_modules? or do I have to change that slash since I moved it?

Comment: I usually have 2 gitignore files but I imagine if you add the correct file path, it should work as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217509/discussion-between-kevgill95-and-hyetigran).

Answer (score 1):

By the way you have your project structured, it looks like the server is never getting spun up. It's common to see a `package.json` file for client and server both.

See an example directory below:
[image]

1. Put all the react stuff in a separate directory i.e. red box
2. You can keep your server.js file in the root directory. npm install your dependencies for the server such as cors, express, dotenv etc. i.e. blue box
3. Since you're using Heroku to host, make sure to add the following script i.e. green box
4. Also, since you're using environment variables for sendGrid, make sure you set them in Heroku settings tab. See below image
   [image]